# Running Metaplex on localhost

Tags: blockchain, web3js, solana, metaplex

Trying to run Metaplex with locally hosted test validator. The wallet seems to be connecting correctly and showing the balance as expected. But it fails to initialize the store. Whenever I press "init store" I run into a timeout waiting for the transaction confirmation.

To enable connecting to localhost I've modified ENDPOINTS in 'connection.ts by adding the following to the array:

```
{
    name: 'localnet' as ENV,
    endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8899',
    ChainId: ChainId.Devnet,
}
```

Upon a closer investigation it seems that the init store does not actually deploy the programs to the local blockchain.

Comment: You are trying to connect to localhost but your chain id points to `DEVNET`?
Also check if you can actually start a local test validator normally.

Comment: I've checked the connection object via a debugger and the RPC endpoint is the localhost with correct port.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Metaplex" in your orginal post you are referring to the Web UI here https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/tree/master/js/packages/web keep in mind this UI does a lot of stuff.

As you have noted in your update: Metaplex is composed of many different program accounts. You would have to locate each of these accounts then "--clone" them on the solana-test-validator command line in order to ensure Metaplex works.

AFAIK there is no script or instructions about how to set up Metaplex from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The Metaplex storeFront is deprecated and is no longer maintained by the Metaplex Team. So i will advice for building an NFT Marketplace better use the  Auction house contract for that. Here is the link for Auction house [link](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/auction-house)